# PHP - sum array condition

Tags: php

I want to sum all data from inside a foreach loop and compare this to values in an outer foreach using jquery, but I don't know how to sum all of the data points from my inner foreach.

Here is the view:

```html
<?php
$a = array(5,15,25);
$sum = 0;

foreach($a as $b) {
    $sum += $b;
    if($sum < 30) {
        echo "<br>" . $sum;
    }
}
?>
```

my answer: 5 20

expectation : 20 25

Comment: `jquery`, but `php` tag?

Comment: Where does the *outer foreach* come into this?

Comment: your expectation is wrong, the answer you are getting is correct

Comment: Could you expand your example input and output for us please?

Comment: What is the meaning of the expected result? What do the numbers 20 and 25 represent?

Comment: I just want to produce value 20 25

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are a new contributor so welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Let's take a look at your code. You are executing the line `echo "<br>" . $sum;` at every iteration of the foreach loop.

Let's try to analyse the loop, iteration after iteration.

Iteration 1 (element 5):
Add 5 to `$sum` -> `$sum = 5`.
Is `$sum` smaller than 30? Yes! -> print `<br> 5`.

Iteration 2 (element 15):
Add 15 to `$sum` -> `$sum = 20`.
Is `$sum` smaller than 30? Yes! -> print `<br> 20`.

Iteration 3 (element 25):
Add 25 to `$sum` -> `$sum = 45`.
Is `$sum` smaller than 30? No -> nothing to print.

This is basically what your code is doing. Remember that, at the end of every iteration, you add the current array value to `$sum`. The starting value for `$sum` is 0 so at the end of each iteration you'll have:

```
$sum = 5 (0 + 5)
$sum = 20 (5 + 15)
$sum = 45 (20 + 25)
```

As you can see the output is correct. Why are you expecting to get `20 25`?

Comment: because I want to produce with value : 20 25